# how to animate bar chart from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts

I am trying to make a bar chart and the bar animates from top to bottom right now, but I want it to animate from bottom to top. How do I get it go from bottom to top?

**CSS**

```
.bar {
width:50px;
height:250px;
list-style-type:none;
}
.bar p {
background-color:#63F;
}
.bar span { 
padding-left:15px;
left:100%;  
}
#content ul {
list-style-type:none;
}
#content ul li {
float:left;
margin:50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="bar">
      <p><span>50%</span></p>
    </div><br>
    Freshmen                    
  </li>
</ul>
</content>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="../../jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bar").each(function(){
        var length = $(this).find("span").html();
        $(this).find("p").delay(500).animate({'height':length},3500,function(){$(this).find("span").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

["click here to see it in jsfiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/saolaoane/6zqSS/)

Answer (score 3):

You can define **position:absolute** to your **bar**. Write like this:

```
.bar {
width:50px;
height:250px;
list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
}
.bar p {
background-color:#63F;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6zqSS/1/

Comment: thank you for help. can you please explain to me why they need to be positioned?

Comment: In HTML by default the height increase from top to bottom. So, that why we use position:absolute with bottom:0 to make P at the start from bottom of .bar DIV. Now when P height increase there no way to expand bottom.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/t4THf/5/

**CSS**

```
.perfect
{
    padding-top:30px;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#efefef;
}
.perfect .bar
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:40px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.perfect .bar .slideup
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.perfect .bar .slideup span
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin:5px;
    top:-30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="perfect">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>20%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>30%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>10%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>70%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>100%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>50%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>60%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>55%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>70%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="slideup">
            <span>70%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
     $(".bar").each(function(){
        var length = $(this).find("span").html();
        $(this).find(".slideup").delay(500).animate({'height':length},
"slow",function(){$(this).find("span").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Click here for [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4THf/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve this using css keyframes, for example for webkit http://jsfiddle.net/kudoslabs/YddaY/

css

```
dl{ position: relative ; height: 200px ; }
dt,dd{ position: absolute ; }
dd{ height: 70% ; width: 30px ; background: grey ; bottom: 20px ; -webkit-animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear; }
dt{ bottom: 0 ; }
@-webkit-keyframes animate-bar{
    0% {height: 0% ; }
}​
```

html

```
<dl>
    <dt>Freshman</dt>    
    <dd>70%</dd>
</dl>​
```

Comment: Kudos - are you able to demonstrate how to do this so it grows horizontally not vertically.

Comment: @Kudos - I checked out your example and it works perfectly but how does the code change if I want multiple bars? Rather than hard coding adding them dynamically? In my main.js I'm using handlebars to generate the bars and with your code they all have the same height because of the css. I'm trying to pass an array for the height and an array for the lables.Here is my repo:  https://github.com/sbaden/bar-graph.git

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/6zqSS/2/

```
.bar {
    position: relative;
}


.bar p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyframes to animate the css property, e.g. width
Once you set the width of your element (e.g. div) the animation will kick in

```
.animated-bar {
  animation: animateBar 0.25s ease-in;
  @keyframes animateBar {
    0% {
      width: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-bar" style="width: 200px"><div>
```